# How do I create a temp filename in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, filenames

I need to put data in a file since my other function takes a file as input.

How do I create a unique filename in Erlang?

Does something like unix "tempfile" exist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you mean just generate the acutal filename? In that case the safest way would be to use a mix of the numbers you get from now() and the hostname of your computer (if you have several nodes doing the same thing).

Something like:

```
1> {A,B,C}=now().
{1249,304278,322000}
2> N=node().
nonode@nohost
3> lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p-~p.~p.~p",[N,A,B,C])).
"nonode@nohost-1249.304278.322000"
4>
```

Comment: Since not everyone is aware of that: calls to erlang:now() are guaranteed to return unique results each time. Quite useful property...

Comment: Yes, very useful. There is one other thing that is very useful with this way of generating a reference; you get the nodename in there which is very useful if you want to first ensure that the id is always unique (you can treat it as a local reference) and second to know from where the reference comes from. In our system (with n nodes in the cluster and shared datatables etc) we can easily find the logs and information we need about a job using this identifier only (Node + Time).

Comment: It will fail if such file already exists. erlang:now() can't guarantee that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: `erlang:now/0` is deprecated, use `erlang:unique_integer/0` ([docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#unique_integer-1)) instead.

Comment: This has the weakness that it does not protect against a name collision between two concurrent processes.  It is possible for two processes to generate the filename at the same microsecond. I'm currently dealing with an intermittent build failure due to a build tool's use of this timestamp based tmpfile name.

Use the mktemp solution instead.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `TMP = lib:nonl(os:cmd("mktemp")).`

Comment: Slightly uglier, but `string:strip(os:cmd("mktemp"), right, $\n)` can avoid that annoying invisible newline that will usually be returned at the end.

Comment: Shorter version: `lib:nonl( os:cmd( "mktemp" ) )`.

Comment: `lib:nonl/1` was removed in [OTP 21](http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_21.0.readme), the replacement seems to be [`string:chomp/1`](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/string.html).

Answer (score 7):

Or you could do

`erlang:phash2(make_ref())`

for a quick and easy unique indentifier. Unique for up to 2^82 calls which should be enough.for your purposes. I find this easier than formatting a timestamp with node name for use.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer: I just noticed the test_server module which has scratch directory support, worth a look

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/test_server.html#temp_name-1

Comment: It doesn't guarantee this file will not exist in time you will try to make this file. So it is not secure. It is why there is `mkstemp` in `stdlib.h`. `mktemp` from GNU coreutils uses `mkstemp` call internally.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally had this problem -- and my user is using a mix of Windows and Linux systems, so the old tried-and-true `lib:nonl(os:cmd("mktemp"))` method is just not going to cut it anymore.

So here is how I've approached it, both with a `mktemp/1` function that returns a filename that can be used and also a `mktemp_dir/1` function that returns a directory (after having created it).

```
-spec mktemp(Prefix) -> Result
   when Prefix   :: string(),
        Result   :: {ok, TempFile  :: file:filename()}
                  | {error, Reason :: file:posix()}.

mktemp(Prefix) ->
    Rand = integer_to_list(binary:decode_unsigned(crypto:strong_rand_bytes(8)), 36),
    TempPath = filename:basedir(user_cache, Prefix),
    TempFile = filename:join(TempPath, Rand),
    Result1 = filelib:ensure_dir(TempFile),
    Result2 = file:write_file(TempFile, <<>>),
    case {Result1, Result2} of
         {ok, ok}    -> {ok, TempFile};
         {ok, Error} -> Error;
         {Error, _}  -> Error
    end.
```

And the directory version:

```
-spec mktemp_dir(Prefix) -> Result
   when Prefix  :: string(),
        Result  :: {ok, TempDir   :: file:filename()}
                 | {error, Reason :: file:posix()}.

mktemp_dir(Prefix) ->
    Rand = integer_to_list(binary:decode_unsigned(crypto:strong_rand_bytes(8)), 36),
    TempPath = filename:basedir(user_cache, Prefix),
    TempDir = filename:join(TempPath, Rand),
    Result1 = filelib:ensure_dir(TempDir),
    Result2 = file:make_dir(TempDir),
    case {Result1, Result2} of
         {ok, ok}    -> {ok, TempDir};
         {ok, Error} -> Error;
         {Error, _}  -> Error
    end.
```

Both of these do basically the same thing: we get a strongly random name as a binary, convert that to a base36 string, and append it to whatever the OS returns to us as a safe user-local temporary cache location.

On a unix type system, of course, we could just use `filename:join(["/tmp", Prefix, Rand])` but the unavailability of `/tmp` on Windows is sort of the whole point here.

Comment: Function `ensure_dir(Name)` is in `filelib` module. Link - https://erlang.org/doc/man/filelib.html#ensure_dir-1

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for catching that. Fixed. I should probably do a blog post on the various file* and io* modules to give people a head start on how to find what sort of function where. It certainly wasn't obvious to me the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

In OTP 24 there is not `file:ensure_dir`. So I've made something similar:

For directory:

```
mktemp_dir(Prefix) ->
    Rand = integer_to_list(binary:decode_unsigned(crypto:strong_rand_bytes(8)), 36),
    TempDir = filename:basedir(user_cache, Prefix),
    []= os:cmd("mkdir " ++ "\"" ++ TempDir ++ "\""),
    {ok, _} = file:list_dir(TempDir),
    TempDir.
```

For file:

```
mktemp(Prefix) ->
    Rand = integer_to_list(binary:decode_unsigned(crypto:strong_rand_bytes(8)), 36),
    TempDir = filename:basedir(user_cache, Prefix),
    TempFile = filename:join(TempDir, Rand),
    []= os:cmd("mkdir " ++ "\"" ++ TempDir ++ "\""),
    {ok, _} = file:list_dir(TempDir),
    Result = file:write_file(TempFile, <<>>),
    case {Result} of
         {ok}    -> {ok, TempFile};
         {Error}  -> Error
    end.
```